# What methods can I use to validate my source/input data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, self-study

For example, a ticker's price coming from a stock exchange or earnings from a company's financial statements. How can I validate that it's trustworthy as an input into a model?

In my career, I've just plugged into companies' data sources then leveraged the data but I spoke with someone today who challenged me on how can I trust self-reported data into a model.

I'm new to this area, and I'm wondering if there is an approach people take with this problem(i.e. I'm thinking of std dev of mean? anomaly detection? etc but all these assume the time series is correct, to begin with).  I clean the datasets I use for features, but what can do to inspire confidence around the labelled data?

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Physics, "physics", and forensics come to mind.  Secondary sources.  Satellite views of number of cars in parking lots can tell you about how hard working a factory is.  Ephemeris.  Benchmark vs. equivalent or near-neighbors in the space.

Comment: interesting - thank you. You would reference multiple sources to validate.

what about data that is mainly self-reported?

Comment: Forensics.  Math.  You can use near-neighbors even if they aren't the same for Bass diffusion model estimation, so you can use them for other things too.  Humans are poor fabricators of numbers.  Clean data has a smell that is very different than dirty data.